# QMK compile implicit declaration erros

Tags: qmk-firmware

I have a problem while compiling my keymaps for a [Corne](https://github.com/foostan/crkbd) keyboard. I'm currently using Ubuntu and here is the console log:

```
Compiling: quantum/keymap_introspection.c                                                          In file included from ./keyboards/crkbd/keymaps/CrisCL20/keymap.c:19:0,
                 from quantum/keymap_introspection.c:5:
./keyboards/crkbd/keymaps/CrisCL20/keymap.c:26:7: error: implicit declaration of function ‘SFT_L’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
       SFT_L(KC_ESC),    KC_A,    KC_S,    KC_D,  KC_F,KC_G,                         KC_H,    KC_J,    KC_K,    KC_L, KC_SCLN, KC_QUOT,
       ^
./.build/obj_crkbd_rev1_CrisCL20/src/default_keyboard.h:44:4: note: in definition of macro ‘LAYOUT_split_3x6_3’
   {k1A, k1B, k1C, k1D, k1E, k1F}, \
    ^
./keyboards/crkbd/keymaps/CrisCL20/keymap.c:26:7: error: initializer element is not constant
       SFT_L(KC_ESC),    KC_A,    KC_S,    KC_D,  KC_F,KC_G,                         KC_H,    KC_J,    KC_K,    KC_L, KC_SCLN, KC_QUOT,
       ^
./.build/obj_crkbd_rev1_CrisCL20/src/default_keyboard.h:44:4: note: in definition of macro ‘LAYOUT_split_3x6_3’
   {k1A, k1B, k1C, k1D, k1E, k1F}, \
    ^
./keyboards/crkbd/keymaps/CrisCL20/keymap.c:26:7: note: (near initialization for ‘keymaps[0][1][0]’)
       SFT_L(KC_ESC),    KC_A,    KC_S,    KC_D,  KC_F,KC_G,                         KC_H,    KC_J,    KC_K,    KC_L, KC_SCLN, KC_QUOT,
       ^
./.build/obj_crkbd_rev1_CrisCL20/src/default_keyboard.h:44:4: note: in definition of macro ‘LAYOUT_split_3x6_3’
   {k1A, k1B, k1C, k1D, k1E, k1F}, \
    ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
 [ERRORS]
```

I have not tried much since there is not much information out there about this specific issue.

How can I fix it?

Comment: This was [crossposted on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/olkb/comments/1ab85z8/problems_with_qmk_compile/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the `SFT_L(kc)` alias, use the original name `LSFT_T(kc)`.

Comment: That is a solution, but what is the reason for it (working)? What is SFT_L? A (preprocessor) macro? [`LSFT_T`](https://github.com/qmk/qmk_firmware/blob/master/docs/keycodes.md#mod-tap-keys-idmod-tap-keys). Perhaps elaborate a little bit in your answer? (But *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today)

Comment: cont' - E.g., why doesn't the (preprocessor?) alias work?